# How to get value of a row in listview in android

Tags: java, android

I am new in android
The structure of my application consist of:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.reyhane.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

cell.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nationalCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="حذف" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.reyhane.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ListView list;
    public ArrayList<Person> countries = new ArrayList<Person>();
    public ListAdapter adapter;

    public void fillPerson(String nationalCode) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setNationalCode(nationalCode);
        person.setName("reza");
        person.setLastName("hghgh");
        person.setPhone("231345");
        countries.add(person);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fillPerson("6768767");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Person person = (Person) o;
                openAddPersonActivity(person.getNationalCode());
            }
        });
    }

    public void openAddPersonActivity(String nationalCode) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPerson.class);
        if (nationalCode != null)
            i.putExtra("nationalCode", nationalCode);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.reyhane.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by reyhane on 11/24/16.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    ListAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainActivity.countries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView nationalCode;
        TextView name;
        TextView lastName;
        TextView phone;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);

            holder.nationalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nationalCode);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.lastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Button deleteBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        holder.nationalCode.setText(this.mainActivity.countries.get(position).getNationalCode());
        holder.name.setText(this.mainActivity.countries.get(position).getName());
        holder.lastName.setText(this.mainActivity.countries.get(position).getLastName());

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                mainActivity.countries.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My problem:
As you see in my application, i have list of person in listview.
In this form i add person and delete and edit it.
I can remove each record of listview but i can not get nationalCode value of person of each reacord in listview to fetch person from database by this nationalcode and edit it.
How do i do?
please help me

Comment: in your onItemClickedListener do this `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The national code is: " + list.get(position).getNationalCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` thats how you should get the national code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
                {
                    String nationalcode = (String) ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nationalcode)).getText();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NATIONAL CODE "+nationalcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openAddPersonActivity(nationalcode);

                }
            });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: were you able to see the toast.?

Comment: are you getting any exception.?

Comment: No any exception i really confused

Comment: How do i do?please help me

Comment: Are you getting any exception.?

Comment: My friend any exception,i build and run application and click to each row but i did not any result, i really confused

Comment: Try calling fillPerson("6768767"); after setcontentview()

Comment: So you are able to see the list. and when you click on the item You are not getting anything. right.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130671/discussion-between-reza-ramezani-matin-and-shanu).

Comment: i find solution

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
openAddPersonActivity(countries.get(position).getNationalCode());
```

FYI, the list.setOnItemClick doesn't work

add this into your ListAdapter:

```
holder.nationalCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"Country Code = "+MainActivity.countries.get(position).getNationalCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity, AddPerson.class);
        if (nationalCode != null)
           i.putExtra("nationalCode", nationalCode);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and if you click country code in listview item then it will detected;

Comment: I have not 'countries' ,it is simple,i store person data in database really

Comment: "countries" are your ArrayList where you store your data

Answer (score 0):

You have not set countries list to your Listview adaptor.

When you are setting the adaptor, pass the countries list to listview adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

It work successfully:

```
holder.nationalCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nationalcode = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nationalCode)).getText();
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "NATIONAL CODE " + nationalcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Person person = countries.get(position);
                openAddPersonActivity(person.getNationalCode());
            }`